# Debian - Stopping MySQL from booting at start

Tags: mysql, debian, boot

I have MySQL on my computer for development purposes, but most of the time I don't use it.
How can I configure my Debian so it won't start MySQL at boot, but only when I tell it to ( using `service mysql start`).

I did the same thing to apache2 using,

```
 update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

But I couldn't find a way to do this with MySQL.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want `update-rc.d mysql disable`.  You don't want remove, As noted in the update-rc.d manpage:

`A common system administration error is to delete the links with the
    thought that this will "disable" the service, i.e., that this will pre‐
    vent  the  service from being started.  However, if all links have been
    deleted then the next time  the  package  is  upgraded,  the  package's
    postinst  script  will  run  update-rc.d  again and this will reinstall
    links at their factory default locations`

Answer (score 2):

Since Debian 8 (Jessy) using systemd by default, so try this:

```
systemctl list-units | grep mysql    # check for mysql unit name
systemctl disable mysql.service      # or whatever you find at prev step
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update-rc.d -f mysql remove
```

or:

```
update-rc.d mysql disable
```